# How to get worker.threadId inside a worker using worker_threads?

Tags: node.js, node-worker-threads, nodejs-cluster

I'm using the `nodejs` with `worker_threads` module.

I created several workers.

**I need to get the id of each worker within the worker itself.**

I know that in the `cluster` module, just call `cluster.worker.id` from within the worker and it returns the worker's id.

**I need** to do this **with** `worker_threads`, but I don't see a function option to call this from within the worker using when I'm just using threads.

I don't find a function for this in the documentation.

The closest I've come to this is calling `worker.threadId` , but that **only works on the parent thread**.

So I have the expense of forwarding the id through the parent until it reaches the child via `postMessage` to the child.

That's too much dirty code.

I miss a **function similar** to `cluster.worker.id` **inside a child** `worker_threads`.

Does anyone know a better solution to **calling** `worker.threadId` **from inside a child** `worker_threads`?

<<< **EDIT** >>>

**The solution has been found!**

I found the solution!

You need to add `threadId` as an `import` of `worker_threads`.

```
import { Worker, isMainThread, parentPort, threadId } from 'worker_threads';
```

And call `threadId` inside the child worker.

The worker `id` will come natively.

I asked this question in the official nodejs directory on github.

A person named benjamingr gave this solution.
[github](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/50797)